# How to read HTTP header from response using .NET HttpWebRequest API?

Tags: c#, twitter, oauth, httpwebresponse

My app currently uses OAuth to communicate with the Twitter API.  Back in December, Twitter upped the rate limit for OAuth to 350 requests per hour.  However, I am not seeing this.  I am still getting 150 from the [account/rate_limit_status](https://web.archive.org/web/20101102184058/http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-account%C2%A0rate_limit_status) method.

I was told that I needed to use the `X-RateLimit-Limit` HTTP header to get the new rate limit.  However, in my code, I do not see that header.

Here is my code...

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(newURL);
request.Method = "GET";
request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

If I inspect the `response`, I can see that it has a property for `Headers`, and that there are 16 headers.  However, I do not have `X-RateLimit-Limit` in the list.

[image]
<sub>(source: [yfrog.com](http://img10.yfrog.com/img10/5997/33201085434am.png))</sub>

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I dont know anything about twitter API, but shouldn't the X-RateLimit-Limit header used in Request, not recieved wia Response?

Comment: @Yossarian, no; it should be in the response: http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Rate-limiting

Comment: @Yossarian - the `request` only has two headers: Content-Type and Host.  And those are RequestHeaders.  The `X-RateLimit-Limit` comes from Twitter, so I would have assumed it would be in the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the raw response text (e.g., with Fiddler). If the header isn't there, no amount of C# code is going to make it appear. :) From what you've shown, it seems the header isn't in the response.

Update: When I go to: http://twitter.com/account/rate_limit_status.xml there is no `X-RateLimit-Limit` header. But when I go to http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.xml, it's there. So I think you just need to use a different method.

It still says 150, though!

Comment: Thanks Craig.  The problem is that the `rate_limit_status` is not rate limited.  Neither was the method I was using (the `access_token` OAuth Method).  If I use a method that is rate limited, like the `public_timeline`, it's there.  So it seems that Twitter only sends those header values for methods that are actually rate limited.

Answer (score 12):

You should simple be able to use:

```
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
  string limit = response.Headers["X-RateLimit-Limit"];
  ...
}
```

If that doesn't work as expected, you can do a watch on response.Headers and see what's in there.

Comment: It's working not, if  the Response is not an `200 OK`. If the server gives an `550 Internal Server Error` or an `404 Not Found`, the application will break with an `Exception` on `GetResponse`.