# HttpWebRequest/Response on localhost (WebException: operation timed out)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I need to inspect some HTTP headers and so I'm using C#'s `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` classes.

I'm developing using Visual Studio 2012 and would like to test out the request and response on my localhost so I can see what kind of headers I'm dealing with (I use devtools in Chrome so I can see there, but I want to make sure my code is returning the proper values).  When I simply put in `http://localhost:[Port]/` it doesn't connect.

I can see that it repeatedly is making a request to the server and eventually I get the exception `WebException: The Operation has timed out`.  If I add `request.KeepAlive = false'` then I get the exception `WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server`.

So I'm wondering:

1. Is something wrong with my code? (see below)
2. How can I test `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` on localhost?

I've tried using the IP address in place of "localhost" but that didn't work (ex `http://127.0.0.1:[port]/`)

Code:

```
   public class AuthorizationFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
   {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        string url = "http://127.0.0.1:7792/";
        string responseString;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        //request.KeepAlive = false;
        //request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(request);


        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(responseString);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(e.Message);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(e.Source);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You won't see any information in Chrome Dev tools since the request is made by the application, not by the browser.

Comment: @Marthijn That makes sense.  Is there a tool or plugin of some kind that can intercept header info made from the application?  I was hoping that I could just output the response by using `Debug.Write` and take a look at what is sent in the output window of VS2012.

Comment: Just set breakpoints in your application, see this question for a screenshot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371835/how-to-read-http-header-from-response-using-net-httpwebrequest-api

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/)? [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) will show you all the HTTP Requests, all headers, response status, with different data views like raw, hex, image etc, a timeline view, HTTPS Connects, pretty much everything.

There are also Firefox extensions like [httpfox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/). But I strongly recommend you try out Fiddler.

Comment: I haven't but I've heard the name thrown around a lot.  I'll have to take a look at it.

Comment: Fiddler just seems kind of overkill though.  I'd really just like to know if the code will successfully connect to the server and if when connected, will I be able to read the header info and do the logic accordingly...

Comment: Will Fiddler be able to tell me why my request keeps timing out?